# MMORPG game Server and Client with a high level communication library

Tags: java, c#, server

I am developing a MMORPG game for Mobile (mostly windows mobile 8.1), I have written the server using Java and client side using C#. I am using JSON objects for the communication between server and client. I have a TCP connection and a UDP connection.

The mechanism I am using right now is that I send a Request object to the server and waits for a response Object. Rather than this is there a good high level communication library or something that I can use just to make it easier and effective. ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stream asynchronous events and only do request response when your game cannot continue unless you have a response e.g. login.

You can use netty on the server and any one of a number of JSON libraries on the JSON side.  I imagine C# has a similar range of communication and JSON libraries.